# coupled differential equations with fractions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out what to do with these coupled differential equations:

$$x'=\frac{-y}{y^2+x^2}$$
$$y'=\frac{x}{y^2+x^2}$$ and I have intial conditions $x(0)=1$, and $y(0)=0$. I tried adding and subtracting them, but it didn't help me much...

Comment: Are these derivatives wrt each other or some third variable?

Comment: a third variable

Comment: Change to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if the equations hold
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \left(x^2 + y^2\right) &= 2xx' + 2yy'
\\&= -2x \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} + 2y \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}
\\&= \frac{-2xy + 2xy}{x^2 + y^2}
\\&= 0
\end{align}
Thus,
$$
x^2 + y^2 = \text{constant}
$$
What can $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ be?

Comment: I still am a bit confused on the nature of x(t) and y(t)....if x^2+y^2 is a constant then are x and y both linear equations? how would I figure out the coefficients?

Comment: Think of $(x,y)$ as a vector. What does $x^2 + y^2 = $ constant mean in terms of this vector? How can we parametrize such a vector?

Comment: Alternatively, set $\frac{1}{K} = x^2 + y^2$. Then the equations read $x' = -Ky$ and $y' = Kx$. Do you recognize these equations? If it's still not clear, try writing $x''$ in terms of $x$. I don't want to go much further with hints because this is a pretty standard problem worth working through as much as possible on your own.

Comment: Thank you! the second comment is very helpful. I don't recognize anything because I have no experience with differential equations since I haven't had to use them in any class and they were never covered in lecture other than a very simple example. my professor just put a problem that boiled down to this on the homework. It's very frustrating but I suppose now is the time I finally become acquainted with them.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I'll say that it's a standard result that $x'' = - K^2 x$ has solutions $x(t) = A\cos  K t + B \sin K t$.

Answer (score 0):

For finding an expression in $y$ and $x$,

Note that $${{dy\over dt}\over {dx\over dt}} = {dy\over dx}$$

So, $${dy\over dx}= -{x\over y}$$

And so

$$x^2+y^2 = c = r^2 \tag{circle}$$

Note that this could be parameterized as $$(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))$$

See that $$x' = -\frac yc$$ and so $$x'' = -kx$$ Solving this second degree differential equation (or comparing it with simple harmonic motion) will confirm the above.